# Use value of id to search for class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the value of an html element via Id. I now want to use that value to loop through all the elements with the class from the id.val. How can I search for a variable as a class.

```
$(".BtnSettings").click(function () {
        var Daytime = $("#Daytime").val();
//Here i dont know what to do. Instead of .Daytime I want to search for the var Daytime. Or for $("#Daytime").val() obviously, doesnt matter.
        $('.Daytime').each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", true); // Element(s) are now enabled.
        });
    })
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('.'+Daytime)` ? If not then your question is VERY unclear. Please post a snippet with HTML and expected result in a [mcve]

Comment: I just want to use the var Daytime as the   $('.Daytime').each(function () { instead of the .Daytime to search for the value of #Daytime

Comment: @mplungjan yes thanks that what i meant

Comment: Feel free to delete the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the attr method of jquery to look for a specific attribute just set a value. if you want to change value of said attribute the second parameter of the function will set it for you like.

```
Daytime.attr("class","newClass")
$("#Daytime").attr("class")
```

will give you the class of `#Daytime`

Comment: This is not what was asked. They want to find the elements that have the class matching the value in the Daytime field

Comment: oh. my bad. :bow